# Jerigonza a su palabra original

Tags: c++, c

Soy nuevo es esto de C++ y recientemente nos dejaron algunos ejercicios de practica en el curso, uno de estos era la converción de palabras en jerigonza a su palabra original, antes de este ejercicio habia uno donde debíamos convertir una oración a jeringoza. Pense que solo seria hacer el contrario de este, aqui esta el codigo de la jerigonza:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int jerigonza(string);

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string jerin(string);

int main(void){
    string frase="";
    cout<<"Ingrese tu frase a traducir"<<endl;
    cin>> frase;
    string fraseconv = jerin(frase);
    cout<<"La nueva frase en jerigonza es: "<< fraseconv << endl;
    return 0;
}

string jerin(string frase){
    for(int i=0; i < frase.size();i++){
        switch(frase[i]){
            case 'a': frase.insert(i+1, "pa"); i+=2; break;
            case 'e': frase.insert(i+1, "pe"); i+=2; break;
            case 'i': frase.insert(i+1, "pi"); i+=2; break;
            case 'o': frase.insert(i+1, "po"); i+=2; break;
            case 'u': frase.insert(i+1, "pu"); i+=2; break;
        }
   }
   return frase;
}
```

Asi que pense cambiar el case 'a' por "pa" y viceversa pero me da un error de multicaracter, así que intente hacer un for para este caso:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;

int oracioncor (char);

int main (){
char frasep [50]={};
cout <<"Ingrese su frase con p"<<endl;
cin.getline(frasep,50);
for(int i=0;i>50;i--){
    for(int j=0;j>50;j--){
      char pa=1, pe=2;
      if(i==1 && j==2)
    frasep[50]= frasep[i];
    cout<<frasep[i];

return 0;
    }
 }
}
```

Mi intención era basicamente eliminar pa que en este caso seria igual a 1, pero al correr el codigo no devuelve nada,¿Me falta algo en el for?, o simplemente estoy completamente mal.
Gracias por la ayuda.

Edición 1:
Basicamente se debe de poner una palabra de este modo: Hopolapa copomopo epestapas y retornar "Hola como estas"

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de lo que llamas jerigonza

Comment: Suena difícil ya que papapapa es papa y papa es pa y pa no es nada... Salía error porque los strings van con comillas dobles `"` y los char con comillas simples `'`.

Comment: En si la palabra que se pide es de esta forma: Hopolapa copomopo epestapas y retornar "Hola como estas".@Japv

Comment: Intente poner las comillas dobles a el primer codigo para que fuese case "pa", pero de igual forma de da este error: "invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]" @ArtEze.

Comment: @firststeps02 Entonces podría usarse `strcmp`, que es para comparar dos strings, de alguna manera, quizás con un `for`, cortar la frase desde la posición actual, los dos siguientes caracteres.